# What are the pros and cons of Quantum Armor and the Modular Powersuits?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I want to know the pros and cons of having the Quantum Armor (including the GraviChestPlate) compared to the pros and cons of the Modular Powersuits (with all modules installed).

**What I don't care about**

- Anything unnecessary for everyday protection (anything extra is bonus, but I don't really care about it. I only care about essential protection and faster moving if possible)
- Cost - It would be nice if it was cheap, but it doesn't have to be if it's worth it.

**What I do care about**

- Armor - I hang around in dangerous places a lot. I want to live to tell about it.

  - Fire Protection - The Nether is full of cool stuff! I want to steal it without dying.
  - Fall Damage Protection - Admit it, everyone has fallen into their quarry hole.

If this matters, I am using the Ultimate Feed the Beast modpack with GregTech on hard mode. Please, if possible, list what prerequisites I need to craft said armors.

Comment: It might help to start at the wiki page for [Quantum Armor](http://ftbwiki.org/Quantum_Armor).

Comment: A full answer to this is a little more involved than I have time to write now, but suffice to say that quantum armor is essentially godmode as long as you keep it powered.  It's extremely expensive though (probably moreso with Gregtech installed).  Odds are if you have to ask you probably can't afford quantum armor yet.  Modular Power Suits are a little less broken but a lot less expensive (and also have the benefit of being able to not install features you don't care about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer being they are both equal, but power suit will better suit your requests(in my opinion)

Quantum offers more protections and a handful of bonuses

Power suits offer SLIGHTLY less protections but can do a whole lot more.

long answer:

Quantum boots let you jump higher and they negate fall damage. Power boots can also negate fall damage, and give you more jump height (in the form of jetboots. They do essentially the same thing, just differently.

Another similar difference is the helmets. Both quantum and Power will let you breathe underwater and keep you fed, but power helmets also gives nightvision(increasing survivability in dark places) and thaumic vision, while the quantum's difference is it protects you from curses (like withering and poison).

If you want mobility, then power suit is the way to go. Quantum only offers jump height and run speed (unless you make gravi suit, which is not easy at all, and power suit does the exact same thing for much less). power suit offers creative mode flight, stepping power(you automatically step up when its a one block height), faster swimming, and teleportation.

Protections... this contest goes to quantum, although power suit can be modified to take very little damage per hit(not even half a heart most of the time), quantum chestplate negates all damage as long as it has power. The quantum helmet is also better suited for fighting things like wither and cave spiders, as it negates curse effects.

Energy use and cosumption with the quantum is cut and dry, but when using the power suit it's an entirely different animal. Basically, the larger capacity batteries you put in the power suit, the slower you will move (the amount is negligible at top tier, though). Also, power suits will charge with basically any form of energy whereas quantum only works off of EU.

It all boils down to preference, but since you are using gregtech I would lean towards Power suits because you would be able to 'finish' it much faster than quantum.

*You could mix the 2, like power boots and legs for mobility, but quantum helmet and chest for protections. That sounds like the best option.*

pre-reqs and recipes are better found in-game using NEI.

Comment: Could the solar helmet/kinetic generator module charge the QuantumSuit?

Comment: @JeffreyLin yes, but extremely slowly. The QuantumSuit holds an awful lot of power

Answer (score 0):

My preference is power helmet (night vision with feeder off),power legs (step, sprint and swim), advanced Nano chest plate (cheap) or GraviChestPlate if I can. Power boots are better if you don't have the Portal mod since long fall boots are superior to any boots (negate all fall damage and has no durability)

One thing to make sure is that you do not add kinetic generator on legs because it kills you without the power chest plate. In nether it builds max heat in a minute or so because one step in the Nether counts as eight in the overworld.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say quantum armor, unless you are using something before IC2 experimental.  Experimental allows you to have a "Quantum Jetpack" which essentially works the same way as the Electric Jetpack, except it also has all the other benefits, such as complete invulnerability, which allows you to survive a direct hit from a fully powered IC2 Nuke, including the potion effects if you have the helmet.
The Power-suits have a certain disadvantage: they have weight; putting on any armor upgrades increase that its weight, which slows you down considerably, even more so while falling or on ice.
I would definitely recommend the usage of Night vision potions alongside the Quantum <s>Suit</s> Armor.

Comment: Woah.. Calm down... (Referring to the second half of your answer)