# What is the best armor in the modpack of Ultra Modded-Survival for Technic Platform?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I tried before Modular Powersuits fully upgraded, now I'm seeking for an armor for PvP with anti-spells and stuff like that. I don't care about costs or time to get it.
[Modpack List](http://www.technicpack.net/modpack/details/ultra-modded-survival-pack.266012)

Currently I'm using [Ultimate armor](http://www.orespawn.com/ultimate-armor.html)

Comment: This is a bit of both too broad and too opinion based. [an example between just TWO of the high end armors](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118675/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-quantum-armor-and-the-modular-powersuits?rq=1) was already pretty lengthy and ultimately just boils down to opinion.

Comment: That answer doesn't in PvP situations, magica spells, OreSpawn Bosses, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best armour in captainsparklez ultra modded survival would be the Royal guardian armour. Its all enchanted. The boots have feather falling which can get annoying sometimes. The sword can have around 500-750 attack damage. Another one is modzilla armour which is made from killing mobzilla and collecting the drops (mobzilla scales)

Comment: Can other players kill me with ANYTHING included in the modpack with that armors?

Comment: There will always be something that can kill you Example: the unstable ingots are an instant kill! They can't kill you one hit so you can run I guess. I don't really understand what you mean can other players kill you of course?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want. If you would prefer high damage resistance and extra powers such as automatically being fed or being able to breathe underwater, the Quantum Armour from IC2 is good. Modular Powersuits have almost as good damage resistance but you can get weaponry for them. Also if you want extremely high damage resistance but don't mind vulnerability to explosions, use Red Matter armour from EE3. There is no "best" armour; it all depends on what you want. If you want damage resistance, I would go with Red Matter, but if you want slightly less but also explosion resistance, go with Quantum armour. If you want less damage resistance still, but in-built weapons systems, use modular powersuits. Quantum armour will protect you from all fall damage (all Y values up to roughly 1600) and all weaponry, but the charge wears down. When it runs out it does not protect you. As an added bonus the quantum helmet will keep you at 9 hunger and allow you to breathe underwater until the charge runs out. The legs will allow you to run 3.4x faster, and the boots give you fall damage resistance and give a jump/speed boost when left-CTRL is pressed. Red Matter armour is indestructible and blocks 90% of damage, but does not provide as good explosive resistance as the other armours (but will still protect from all but the biggest explosions, including an IC2 nuclear reactor meltdown at extremely close proximity), and modular powersuits will not block as much damage but the weapon systems are very effective (particularly the plasma cannon).

Comment: I want an armor for PvP, I don't want to die to spells, ars magica 2, mobs spawn, etc

Comment: If you don't want the players dying to mob spawns diable mob spawning. Use /gamrule domobspawning (or mobspawning I don't know which one) false

Comment: I'm not the owner, I can't edit config files.